# $A(t)$ measurable. Does there exists measurable $x(t)\in\ker A(t)$?

Tags: matrices, measure-theory

I have a matrix function $t\mapsto A(t)$, say on $[0,1]$, which is measurable with $A(t)\in\mathbb C^{n\times m}$, $m < n$. If $A(t)$ is not injective a.e., does there exist a non-vanishing measurable function $t\mapsto x(t)$ such that $x(t)\in\ker A(t)$ for a.e. $t\in [0,1]$? Or better: $x\in L^\infty(0,1)$.

One may assume that $m=n$ and that $A(t)$ is selfadjoint since we can replace $A(t)$ be $A(t)^*A(t)$.

If $E$ is the exceptional set where $A$ is not injective and if there exists a measurable set $E'\subset E$ with positive measure such that $\bigcup_{t\in E'}\operatorname{Im}A(t)\neq\mathbb C^m$, then I am done because I can pick $x$ outside this union and set $x(t) := P_{\ker A(t)}x$, where $P_{\ker A(t)}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker A(t)$.

Comment: What about $x \equiv 0$?

Comment: Of course, I don't want that. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I could answer my question myself (without too much algebra ;-)). I assume that $A(t)\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ is selfadjoint for all $t\in [0,1]$. Also, I set $N(t) := \ker A(t)$ and $R(t) := \operatorname{Im}A(t)$. In addition $P_{N(t)}$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $N(t)$.

For $x\in\mathbb C^m$ define $N_x := \{t : P_{N(t)}x\neq 0\}$. This is a measurable set (since $P_{N(t)} = -\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb T}(A(t)-\lambda I)^{-1}\,d\lambda$, where $\mathbb T$ is the unit circle). Let us assume that $|N_x| = 0$ for all $x\in(\mathbb Q + i\mathbb Q)^m$. Then also $|N|=0$, where $N := \bigcup_{x\in(\mathbb Q + i\mathbb Q)^m}N_x$.

Let $t\notin N$. Then for all $x\in(\mathbb Q + i\mathbb Q)^m$ we have $t\notin N_x$ and hence $P_{N(t)}x = 0$, which means $x\in R(t)$. This proves $(\mathbb Q + i\mathbb Q)^m\subset R(t)$. But as $R(t)$ is closed, it follows that $R(t) = \mathbb C^m$ and thus $N(t) = R(t)^\perp = \{0\}$. Therefore, $A(t)$ is invertible for all $t\notin N$ (i.e., for a.e. $t$). As we excluded this case, there exists $x\in\mathbb C^m$ such that $|N_x|>0$. Then, setting $x(t) := P_{N(t)}x$ is a function as desired. As $\|x(t)\|\le\|x\|$ also $x\in L^\infty$ holds.

EDIT: This reasoning can actually be raised to any separable Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

This should be true, and it follows from the way the system $A \cdot x = 0$ is solved. Consider all $t$ for which $A(t)$ has the rank $r$ equal to the rank of a certain $r\times r$ minor. This is a measurable set. ( the minor is $\ne 0$ and all the larger minors are $0$). On this set, we know how to solve the system, and we can make the solution depend rationally on the entries of $A$ ( and some free parameters, which can be chosen constant). So we can make a measurable choice for a solution of the system.

Comment: Actually, I don't fully understand this. By "minor" you mean the determinant of any square submatrix, right? I think I am more or less with you when $r = m-1$. But what if $r$ is smaller? Then, I think, you've only shown that for any $t$ I can find a basis of the kernel in which each vector depends rationally on the entries of $A(t)$ (entrywise). But for another $t$ the rational dependence might be totally different. How do I pick a fixed vector for every $t$?

Comment: @amsmath: I see the issue...order in a certain way the $r\times r$ minors ( it's a finite set, so whatever total order you choose). Then for those $t$ such that rank $A(t)$ is exactly $r$, choose the first $\r\times r$ minor that is not $0$. Solve the system.  You have a measurable partition of the set where rank is $r$, on each piece you make a rational choice. No issues with double defining.

Comment: What do you mean by the partition? Let's say from now on the minor is always the upper left one (I think we can actually assume this by transforming the matrix appropriately).

Comment: Although I could answer my question myself (see below), I am still interested in this more algebraic approach.

Comment: @amsmath: the way it's formulated, the problem seems too simple to be interesting. Perhaps if $A$ was continuous, and you wanted a continuous choice of a vector in the kernel, then yes, it is more interesting. The  (Borel) measurable functions are very flexible.

Comment: For me the problem was interesting because I couldn't solve it right away. For continuous $A$ I know that a continuous choice is possible. But I was not sure if this is also true if "continuous" is replaced by "measurable".